# how to change form values on selecting required values using laravel 5 and js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I am facing a problem couples of hours has been passed but i am not able to find my solution.
what i want is i have a from where i am adding a property in my form there two radio buttons 1- Vacational 2- Longterm .

If i select vacational and submit my form my form values submitted  after submitting the values are shown on front end and there is button Rates when i click on this button the popup appears:

It shows 1- Season 2- Dates 3- Daily 4- Weekly 5- Monthly ( in case if i select radion button vacational) what i want here if i select radio button longterm the form should display value 1- Season 2- Dates 3- Monthly not daily and weekly but i am unable to show my required values:

My HTML where radio options is:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="is_vacation" name="property_type" checked> Vacation
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="is_long_term" name="property_type"> Long Term
</label>
```

and i am doing like this of js code:

```
function longterm() {
    alert("1");
    document.getElementById('daily').style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById('weekly').style.display ='none';
}
```

and my form where i am giving ids:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Season</th>
        <th>Dates</th>
        <th id="daily" style="width: 150px; ">Daily</th>
        <th id="weekly" style="width: 150px; ">Weekly</th>
        <th id="monthly"  style="width: 150px; ">Monthly</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I want to display only 3 options 1 - Season 2- Dates 3- Monthly how i can do that your help will be really appreciated! Need your help!

Comment: You are only hiding the headers, you need to hide all the cell as well. Removing the header doesn't remove the cells in the tbody

Comment: any logical help?

Comment: can we have chat..

Comment: Get all your table headers and loop through storing the index of the columns you want to remove and remove the header. Then loop over all the rows in tbody removing the td at the indexes identified before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the suggestion I had in the comment of your original post. It could certainly be trimmed down and optimized however I wanted to illustrate what is actually happening.

```js
window.removeColumns = function removeColumns(idsToRemove) {
  // get the table to remove the columns from
  var table = document.querySelector('#tbl');
  // get all the headers in that table
  var headers = table.querySelectorAll('thead td');
  var removeIndex = [];
  // loop over all the headers
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    // loop over the id array passed in 
    for (var removeCheck = 0; removeCheck < idsToRemove.length; removeCheck++)
      // check if the headers id matches any of the ids passed in
      if (headers[i].id == idsToRemove[removeCheck]) {
        // remove the header
        headers[i].parentNode.removeChild(headers[i])
        // mark the column index for removal later
        removeIndex.push(i);
      }
  }
  // get all the rows
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#tbl tbody tr');
  // loop over the rows
  for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {
    // get all the cells
    var cells = rows[r].querySelectorAll('td');
    // loop over the remove indexes
    for (var c = 0; c < removeIndex.length; c++)
      // remove the cell from the row
      rows[r].removeChild(cells[removeIndex[c]]);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <th>
      <tr>
        <td id="testRemoval">Remove</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
      </tr>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Remove</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Remove</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="window.removeColumns(['testRemoval']);" value="remove column" />
```

If this solves your problem please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.